# How to select data where value in a comma split column when using hive sql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Let's say I have 2 tables: t1 and t2, the data looks like below:
[image]

Both colA and colB are stored as string.As you can see, the data in colB is splited by comma.
Now I want to make a join between 2 tables and the condition is that if colA's value can match colB's value after splited by comma.
I imagine the code may looks like:
`select * from t1 join t2 on t1.colA in split(t2.colB,',')`
and the result should look like:
[image]

I wonder how can I achieve the same effect in Hive sql. I hope my statement is clear. Please help if you have any idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the data model.  Storing multiple values in a string is just not the SQL way to store data.  The values should be in separate rows.

If you are stuck with someone else's really, really bad data model, you can use it, but the query is much less efficient than it otherwise would be:

```
select *
from t1 join
     t2
     on ',' || t2.colB || ',' like '%,' || t1.colA || ',%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `array_contains`:

```
select * 
from t1 
join t2 
on array_contains(split(t2.colB,','), t1.colA)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from t1 
join (select t2.* 
        from t2 lateral view outer explode(split(t2.colB,',')) e as colB_exploded
     ) t2 
on t2.colB_exploded=t1.colA
```